# Combine multiple tiff into one tiff

Tags: imagemagick

I want to combine some shots using a median evaluation in Imagemagick to improve image quality. After I output them in jpg and align them in Hugin, I use cmd:

```
magick convert *.jpg -evaluate-sequence median OUT.jpg
```

I can get a good result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2jVw.jpg)

However, after I output them in **tif** and combine them in cmd:

```
magick convert *.tif -evaluate-sequence median OUT.tif
```

I get a red background tif:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCkm7.jpg)

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: For IM 7, use magick not magick convert. There are some recently found bugs in both IM 6 and IM 7 handling tiff files that are being fixed for the 7.0.10.49 and should be released soon. You can try the 7.0.10.49beta and see if your issue is fixed. I believe I had a similar issue which is fixed in this beta. What version of IM are you using and what version of libtiff?

Comment: The problem is solved after I try the 7.0.10.49beta and the result is quite well! Thank you!